# Array title not showing up in Swagger UI Models

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have a `Response` object and an array of `Response` objects with `"title": "Responses"`. But `Responses` title text is not showing up in `Models` section of Swagger UI. Is this expected or something wrong with my swagger definition ?
I am using the master branch from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

Swagger `definition` section:

```
    "Response": {
                "type": "object",
                "title": "Response",
                "description": "Response to query.",
                "properties": {
                    "Query": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Query"
                    },
                    "Result": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Result"
                    }
                }
            },
   "Responses": {
                "type": "array",
                "title": "Responses",
                "description": "Array of responses.",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Response"
                }
            }
```

[image: Swagger UI Model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Swagger UI 3.x.  I have a similar API definition.  It works fine in Swagger UI 2.x, but I see the same issue in 3.x.  I don't know if the Swagger UI team is tracking the issue yet.

If you can't wait for a fix, you might want to use the latest distribution from [the 2.x branch](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/2.x).